# Как реализовать такой же эффект?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, dom

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такой же эффект у текста, как на этом сайте: https://www.squarespace.com/404

Текст реагирует на ховер, и учитывает столкновение с другими объектами и отлетает.
В данный момент ищу библиотеки с физикой.

Реализация не имеет значение. Это может быть canvas, DOM.

Comment: https://codersblock.com/blog/javascript-physics-with-matter-js/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection

Comment: @Skywave, `matter-js` я видел, но еще не разбирался, и примеров с текстом и hover у них нету. по поводу второй ссылки, то я не особо понял, как она мне поможет.

Comment: Вопрос актуален?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, конечно. буду благодарен, если поможешь решить эту задачу.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я нашел ответ, который отслеживает соприкосновение элементов, но как бы прикрутить туда физику)
Пример: [Как определить столкновение дивов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/985378/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2)
P.S: После того, как написал комментарий, увидел что вы ответили на этот вопрос) После вашего поста изучал `d3`.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный да, это мой ответ))

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный только он подходит только для дивов, как посчитать коллизии невыпуклых многоугольников тоже понятно, просто чтобы это все вместе собрать надо потратить денек, я когжа нибудь посвещу этому время

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я понимаю, что это не просто. Буду очень признателен. Спасибо!

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный а Вы хотите прям такой же эффект или подобный?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный есть библиотеки с физикой и обработкой коллизий..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94188/discussion-between---and-stranger-in-the-q).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1010342/188366

Comment: http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#svg