# Как определить столкновение дивов?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется код:

При нажатии на кнопку "top" див движется к другому диву вверх:

```js
var c = -1;
function f1(){
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
  var b = document.getElementsByClassName("b");

  b[0].style.top = c--;
}
```

```css
.a{
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.b{
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<button onclick="f1()">Top</button>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при столкновении этих дивов, происходило какое-то действие?   Например, менялся цвет у этих дивов. Возможно ли это реализовать на JavaScript?
Если да, то как?

Comment: а как вы заставляете их столкнуться?

Comment: Отслеживать столкновение координат x и y у обоих блоков и если столкнулись, то запускайте нужную Вам функцию)

Comment: С помощью js, создала кнопки, которые заставляют двигать див, вправо влево и.т.д.

Comment: а можете код добавить в ваш вопрос?

Comment: Конечно, нет просто сейчас доступа к компьютеру, а в телефонной версии нет возможности добавить сточки кода

Comment: Код уже есть в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я собрал пример в котором используется сравнение значений `getBoundingClientRect` для проверки коллизий, все что связано в этом примере с `d3` - к делу не относится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let size = 50;

// данные для 10 квадратов
let data = Array(10).fill(0).map((e, i) => ({
  x: Math.random()*(window.innerWidth-size), 
  y: Math.random()*(window.innerHeight-size)
}));

// последний вызов из этой цепочки (.nodes()) возвращает массив добавленых узлов
// соответственно переменная rects содержит его
let rects = d3.select('body')
  .selectAll('span')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('span')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('width', size + 'px')
  .style('height', size + 'px')
  .style('left', d => d.x + 'px')
  .style('top', d => d.y + 'px')
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", function(d) {
     d3.select(this)
       .style("left", (d.x = d3.event.x) + 'px')
       .style("top", (d.y = d3.event.y) + 'px');
     // каждый раз при перетаскивании вызывается метод проверки коллизий  
     testCollisions(); 
   }))
  .nodes();
 
testCollisions();

function testCollisions() {

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
    rects[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.2)';

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    for (var j=i+1; j<data.length; j++) {

      if (testCollision(i, j)) {
        rects[j].style.backgroundColor = 
        rects[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(150, 0, 0, 0.2)';
      }
      
    }
  }
}

// возвращает true если элементы пересекаются
function testCollision(i, j) {

   i = rects[i].getBoundingClientRect();
   j = rects[j].getBoundingClientRect();
  
  return i.top + i.height > j.top && 
         i.left + i.width > j.left && 
         i.bottom - i.height < j.bottom && 
         i.right - i.width < j.right
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```