# Координаты элемента в окне

Tags: javascript

Можно ли как-нибудь получить координаты элемента относительно окна кроме `getBoundingClientRect`? Без JQuery

Comment: А чем вас `getBoundingClientRect` не устраивает?

Comment: Мне нужно получать координаты при скролле. Эта функция срабатывает слишком много раз, что убивает производительность

Comment: Тогда лучше посмотрите в сторону `throttle`. Это поможет вам не запускать вычисления очень часто. Не думаю, что другие методы получения координат будут быстрее, чем `getBoundingClientRect`.

Comment: Хотелось бы ответить про [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), но думаю по ходу пьесы всплывут подробности, на подобии поддержки осликов  - информации мало.

Comment: @АлександрЕршов уверен проблема не в вызове этого метода. использую его и намного чаще чем при скролле

Comment: вот в этом примере эта фунция используется и в хвост и в гриву https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985387/188366, и к слову, я уверен на 99% процентов что координаты вычисляются 1 раз, причем при отрисовке, а это просто геттер