# Ограничить движение объекта в границах определённой формы

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

> Предлагаю использовать этот вопрос как некий конкурс, далее выделю 500рп тому, чей ответ наберёт большее кол-во голосов "за".

### Условие

Есть код, который позволяет передвигать блок определённых границах (в данном случае это квадрат).

```js
let reg = $('.region'), obj = $('.region .object');

reg.on('mousemove', function(e){
  let p = {
        // region size
        rW: reg.width(), rH: reg.height(),
        // object size
        oW: obj.width(), oH: obj.height(),
        // mouse position
        mY: e.pageY - reg.offset().top, mX: e.pageX - reg.offset().left,
        // object position (center)
        oY: obj.width() / 2, oX: obj.height() / 2
      };
   // object moving
   obj.css({
    'top': p.mY <= p.oY ? 0 : p.mY >= p.rW - p.oW ? p.rW - p.oW : p.mY - p.oY,
   'left': p.mX <= p.oX ? 0 : p.mX >= p.rH - p.oH ? p.rH - p.oH : p.mX - p.oX
   });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100wh; height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.region {
  display: block;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.object {
  display: block;
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="region">
  <div class="object"></div>
</div>
```

Тут даже ежу понятно, что "механика" слишком простая, ибо форма примитивная.

А как быть, к примеру, если форма, по которой нужно будет ограничить движение - будет являться фигурой, допустим **кругом**, **треугольником** или каким-то сложной (относительно) фигурой.

### Задача

Сделать движение элемента по *ограниченной фигуре* (одной или несколько), в приоритете **круг**, **треугольник**.

### Нюансы

1. Как можно меньше трогать вёрстку `html`.
2. *желательно* использовать "динамические" размеры фигуры (т.е. получать от самой фигуры (если это представляет возможности).

### Итоги

Конкурс продлиться до **12.08.19**

Comment: а как задавать сложный контур? svg path?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, как удобнее, главное чтобы это можно было просчитать и взаимодействовать с ним (ну или имитировать движение внутри него).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант.

В лоб за O^2n обходим аппроксимации обоих путей и ищем точки пересечения....

```js
let borderPts = getPoints(border),
    figurePts = getPoints(figure),
    drag;

addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  drag && (drag.element.style.pointerEvents = 'all');
  drag = null;
});

addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  let tr = e.target.getAttribute('transform');
  if (!tr) return;
  let xy = tr.split(/\(|\)|\,/);
  drag = {x: xy[1] - e.x, y: xy[2] - e.y, element: e.target};
  e.target.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
});

let debugPoint = pt => `<circle r=3 fill=none stroke=blue 
  cx="${pt.x}" cy="${pt.y}"></circle>`;

addEventListener('mousemove', e =>  {
  if (!drag) return;
  let intersectionPts = intersect(e.x, e.y);  
  let canMove = e.target === border && intersectionPts.length === 0;
  drag.element.setAttribute('stroke', canMove ? 'black' : 'red' ); 
  if (mode.checked)
    debug.innerHTML = intersectionPts.map(debugPoint).join('');
  if (canMove || mode.checked) 
    drag.element.setAttribute('transform', 
      `translate(${drag.x + e.x},${drag.y + e.y})`);  
});

function intersect(x,y) {
    let pts = figurePts.map(pt => [pt[0] + x + drag.x, pt[1] + y + drag.y]);
    let points = [];
    forEachPair(pts, (pt1, pt2) => {
        forEachPair(borderPts, (pt3, pt4) => {
             let intersection = findIntersection(...pt1,...pt2,...pt3,...pt4);
             intersection && points.push(intersection);           
        });
    });
    return points;
}

function forEachPair(pts, f) {
    for (let i = 0; i<pts.length; i++) 
        f(pts[(i ? i : pts.length)-1], pts[i])
}

function getPoints(path) {
  let precision = 5
  let count = Math.floor(path.getTotalLength()/precision);
  return Array(count).fill(0).map((e,t) => {
    let p = path.getPointAtLength(t*precision);
    return [p.x, p.y];  
  });
}

function findIntersection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {
    // http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
    let denom = (y4 - y3)*(x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3)*(y2 - y1);
    if (denom == 0) 
        return null;
    let ua = ((x4 - x3)*(y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3)*(x1 - x3))/denom;
    let ub = ((x2 - x1)*(y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1)*(x1 - x3))/denom;
    if (ua >= 0 && ua <= 1 && ub >= 0 && ub <= 1)
    return {
        x: x1 + ua * (x2 - x1),
        y: y1 + ua * (y2 - y1)
    };
}
```

```html
<svg width=640 height=155>
<g id="debug"></g>
<path id="border" fill="#0001" d="M27,85C27,85,50,17,80,10C109,2,110,50,156,51C201,51,216,9,281,12C345,14,360,63,438,64C515,64,597,1,620,15C642,28,612,109,538,125C463,140,403,82,295,81C186,79,63,118,63,118A28,28,0,0,1,27,85z"></path>  
<path id="figure" stroke="black" fill="#0001" transform="translate(0,0)" d="M270,54C270,54,312,61,319,59C325,56,318,39,314,36C309,33,293,41,287,39C280,36,274,20,269,19C263,17,254,25,251,30C248,34,246,42,249,46C251,49,270,54,270,54z"></path>
</svg><br><input type="checkbox" id="mode">mode
```

Comment: Кажется это победа :)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 я предлагаю дождаться более простых решений, т.к. это с общем случае очень громоздкое и долгое. например для окружности и треугольника все намного проще

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вопрос  чисто для любопытности почему вы так назвали переменную `denom` что это означает ?Где то еще я видел (ссылку было лень находить) вы класс назвали `rot` .Я конечно все понимаю но почему назвать класса вонючим?

Comment: @Demon__ANT rot-rotation, denom-denominator

Comment: Линейная алгебра. Тогда даже итераций не потребуется.

Comment: У нас есть двумерное пространство и есть функция (или система функций) описывающая точки на ней. Теперь чтобы сделать множество точек, нужно расставить знаки неравенства. Чтоб понять находится ли точка в множестве, нужно проверить, выполняются ли все неравенства, а это O(от числа функций в системе).

Пример: окружность - `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`. Круг - `x^2 + y^2 <= r^2`. Если нужно что-то сложнее, например тор на плоскости, то `x^2 + y^2 <= r_1^2` && `x^2 + y^2 >= r_2^2`.

Answer (score 11):

Для двух окружностей все еще проще чем для прямоугольника, необходимо лишь посчитать что расстояние между центрами не больше чем разница радиусов большой и малой окружности.

В этом случае не сложно сделать так, чтобы при коллизии малая окружность не упиралась и могла перемещаться в направлении курсора не выходя за границы большой.

Для этого вычисляем вектор направления от центра большой окружности до курсора и умножаем его на разницу радиусов.

```js
let x = +bounds.getAttribute('cx');
let y = +bounds.getAttribute('cy');
let dr = +bounds.getAttribute('r') - drag.getAttribute('r');

addEventListener('mousemove', e =>  {
  let dy = y - e.y;
  let dx = x - e.x;
  if (dx*dx + dy*dy < dr*dr) {
    dx = e.layerX;
    dy = e.layerY;
  } else {
    let a = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    dx = x - Math.cos(a)*dr;
    dy = y - Math.sin(a)*dr;
  } 
  drag.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${dx},${dy})`);  
});
```

```html
<svg height=200 width=200 style="margin:-10px">
  <circle id="bounds" r="65" fill="none" stroke="red" cx="100" cy="100"/>
  <circle id="drag" r="20" fill="steelblue" transform="translate(100,100)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Можно еще проще попробовать - сделать 3 окружности. Красную (первая), маленькую (вторая), с радиусом = радиус красной - радиус маленькой (третья). При этом третья должна быть без stroke и fill. И просто смотреть когда e.x, e.y удовлетворяют `x*x + y*y < r*r` где r - радиус 3 окружности.

Comment: @learp ну так то в этом сниппете это и происходит

Comment: Ага, чуть не так понял код. Кстати, можно еще без вычисления sin/cos запоминать последнюю точку перед выходом за границу и оставаться там. Но не так красиво получится и немного дергано.